# scrapy or selenium: How to check it will stop after a time

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I use selenium and scrapy to scrap a website, the selenium firefox window stop at a page for a while (I think more than one minutes).

I don't know when will it stop so  I use control+c to stop it.

And I scrap again.This time,it works well.
But I stil don't know why it was stuck on one page at first time.

Because I set selenium timeout for 20 seconds
`self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)`

I think the problem is on scrapy.

Will scrapy stop when it can't catch data ? How long?
How can I set scrapy timeout to let it find next data to catch if it get stuck??

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html?highlight=timeout#reduce-download-timeout Check this page. May be u can put RETRY_ENABLED = False and  set DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html?highlight=timeout#reduce-download-timeout

Check this page. May be u can put RETRY_ENABLED = False and set DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT as well